# Addition in field

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have not found this particular question via search (here and google), maybe stupid question, but I want to know.

Any $\Bbb F$ contains a multiplicative identity, denoted 1. Assume that characteristic of the $\Bbb F$ is zero.

I understand that by binary operation(addition) we can have $1+1$, but why $1+1\in \Bbb F$?

Comment: Most of the time when the addition is defined it is a function into $\mathbb F$, so the result is always in $\mathbb F$.

Comment: @MattSamuel I see. $\Bbb F \times \Bbb F \to \Bbb F$.

Comment: Correct. So that guarantees it.

Comment: Because $(\Bbb F,+)$ is a group, which means by definition that $a+b\in \Bbb F$ for $a,b\in \Bbb F$. This also holds if $\Bbb F$ has not characteristic zero.

Comment: @Die Not sure if it is correct to write with respect to $1+1 \in \Bbb F$ for $1,1 \in \Bbb F$. Because any set has one of each element?
Do not get angry with me, I'm doing Bsc now.

Comment: Why should I get angry? All I do is  perhaps to say that you have to look into the definitions, but I hope that's OK with you. In this case, the definition of a group $G$. We apply this then for the abelian group $G=(\Bbb F,+)$.

Comment: @Die That's totally fine with me. Was just being cautious.   
This one makes sense, thanks.